# Repeated Exponentiation doubt

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, tetration

I have a somewhat silly doubt about this seemingly basic topic - repeated exponentiation. I've got very little experience regarding this, so please hear me out.

We know that one of the properties of exponents are as follows : $$a^{m^n} = (a^m)^n = a^{mn}$$

However, this property is no longer true for more than two exponents. In that case we have to evaluate them from the highest power to the base.

We have here, $a^{m^{n^p}} \ne a^{mnp}$.

Instead what we do is : $$a^{m^{n^p}} = a^{(m^{(n^p)})}$$

Wikipedia calls this 'right associative' but I don't know what that means here. WHy do we evaluate repeated exponents in this way, and not the other way ?

Comment: "*We know that one of the properties of exponents...*"  No, that is incorrect.  $a^{b^c}$ is meant to be interpreted as $a^{(b^c)}$ not as $(a^b)^c$, whether with two exponents or more.  These are not equal.

Comment: For what its worth, if we really did mean to have $a^{m^{n^{p}}}=a^{mnp}$ why would we bother ever writing it in the harder to read at a glance format.  It would have made far more sense to insist that all variables in the exponent be written on the same line in the same fontsize.  Also, for what its worth, you should be reminded that $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ can fail when dealing with negative or non-real base $a$.

Comment: If you write $10-5-3$ it is usually interpreted as $(10-5)-3$ which might be called left-associative (do the left-hand subtraction first) while $2^{3^4}$ is usually interpreted as $2^{\left(3^4\right)}$ which is called right-associative (do the right-hand exponentiation first)